# How to Join the two values in the same table in sql?

Tags: mysql, sql, join

[image: This is I attached sample table] -   **link for the sample table**

I have a table name as **Customer**. In that table, there are several attributes like customer_id, customer_name, address, country, bill_to_customer, account_start_date, etc...So I want to get the billing customer name, address, country, from that table. In here, ***customer_id*** may be equal to ***bill_to_customer*** or customer_id not equal to bill_to_customer_id. When I want to get the billing customer details, what it does is, go to bill_to_customer value and filter the data of customer_id which matches with the bill_to_customer and give the output. How to write a SQL query to do this?

Comment: You could improve this question by publishing the table definition, sample data and and expected output (all as text).

Comment: Please [use text, not images/links, for text--including tables & ERDs](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/3404097). Paraphrase or quote from other text. Give just what you need & relate it to your problem. Use images only for what cannot be expressed as text or to augment text. Include a legend/key & explanation with an image. Images cannot be searched for or cut & pasted. Also, links die. Insert images/links using edit functions. Make your post self-contained. [ask] [Help] Please in code questions give a [mre].

Answer (score 1):

you can do a self join on table Customer with your bill_to_customer column.

Something like this:

```
SELECT billing.name, billing.address, billing.country FROM Customer cust
INNER JOIN Customer billing ON cust.bill_to_customer = billing.customer_id
WHERE ...further conditions...
```

Comment: btw my solutions assumes there is always a value in column bill_to_customer.
If that´s not the case you may change the inner join to a left join and select fields like COALESCE(billing.name, cust.name).